# ggplot scale x-axis in interplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to scale x-axis in interplot. However, I got the following error:

```
require(scales)
Reverse_TwoSD_Standardization_trans = function() trans_new("Reverse_TwoSD_Standardization", function(Tran) {Tran*2*sd(AAA)+mean(BBB)}, function() 1)

interplot(m=Model1, var1 = 'A', var2 = 'B') +
  xlab('AA') +
  ylab('BB') +
  theme_few() + scale_x_continuous(trans = Reverse_TwoSD_Standardization_trans)
```

Error in paste0(x, "_trans") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: You may need the `()` after "Reverse_TwoSD_Standardization_trans" in use the function.

Comment: I added it. However it seems my function does not work well. I transformed my data previously with (x-mean(x))/(2*SD(X)). I want to back the x axis to the original X. What is your suggested transformation function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my past experience with scale transformations, you need to define a function for your transformation and another function for your inverse.  Your code sample above doesn't appear to meet that criteria.

Without a sample of your data or interplot available for testing, this is the way I would set it up:

```
#define the mean() and 2*sd() globally in order to perform the transformation and the inverse
meanx<-mean(#your x axis variable goes here)
twosdx<-2*sd(#your x axis variable goes here)

#custom transformn
custom<-function(x){
  (x-meanx)/twosdx
}

#inverse custom function
icustom<-function(x){
  y<-x*twosdx+meanx
  print(paste("icustom",x, y))  #debug statement
  return(y)
}


interplot(m=Model1, var1 = 'A', var2 = 'B') +
  xlab('AA') +
  ylab('BB') +
  theme_few() + scale_x_continuous(trans=scales::trans_new("custom", custom, icustom))
```

Substitute in your x variable into the xmean and twosdx definitions and see how it goes.
Once the code is properly working, feel free to remove the print statement from the production code.

Comment: I reversed the place of custom and icustom to create roughly what I liked but I got another issues:
1. I got the numbers: "icustom 0.757092308657784"     "icustom 0.783224367028277"
2. However, I got NA in the plot axis

Comment: @RezaSadeghi, I made an edit to the inverse function for better debugging information. Need to make sure the inverse function is calculating the inverse properly. I had a typo in the original function.

Comment: It computes properly without any nans, like: [1] "icustom -1.43800059446373 -2.30258509299405"    "icustom -1.41186853609323 -2.23100464714044". But I have the following issue:
1. The range of transformed axis is from -1.43 to 4.78. But the plot does not show two tails. I added breaks to scale
scale_x_continuous(trans=scales::trans_new("custom",transform = icustom, inverse = custom), breaks = c(-1,0,1))
it works but if I put c(-1,0,4) it stops.

Comment: 2. Also I found something wired that print(paste("icustom",x, y)). It prints 100 number. Then it prints the exact same numbers. Finally it prints two lines as follows: 
[1] "icustom -1.56735428339767 -2.6569082999694" "icustom 1.27842687314914 5.13820225348837" 
[1] "icustom -1 -1.1028220513173" "icustom 0 1.63635925766173"  "icustom 1 4.37554056664076"

Comment: When it is time to print the plot, the scales tranform is call multiple times. It is called to scale the limits on the axis, the label values and all of the data points.  The labels stay the same but the scale between the labels will change with the transformation.  Since this is a linear transformation, the relative distances between labels remain the same.

Comment: Is there any possibility to I add the maximum value label to the x-axis?